# How to solve problem with functions in API 29?

Tags: c#, api, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I use some functions *(API 29)* and have the same problem.

For example, I have a custom button and want to use `BlendModeColorFilter` to change the color of the icon

```
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    _defaultColor = CustomRoundButton.GetTintColor(Element).ToAndroid();
    var defaultColorFilter = new BlendModeColorFilter(_defaultColor, BlendMode.SrcIn);
    var whiteColorFilter = new BlendModeColorFilter(Color.White, BlendMode.SrcIn);
    
    Control.GetCompoundDrawables()[0].SetColorFilter(Control.GetCompoundDrawables()[0].ColorFilter == defaultColorFilter
    ? whiteColorFilter
    : defaultColorFilter);
}
```

But I have a  mistake
[image]

I updated my Target Framework but I do not know to do
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is common for *Android* to obsolete certain methods then completely remove them in later *SDK's*. The only thing we can do is check for what the actual device supports; add the support for the latest *SDK's*; create compatibility for the older ones; and `pragma` out the warnings so they are not creating build noise.

> **SDK_INT**
>
> The SDK version of the software currently running on this hardware
> device

You can do this at runtime.

<sub>*Modify to suit your needs*</sub>

```
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Q) 
{
     var defaultColorFilter = new BlendModeColorFilter(_defaultColor, BlendMode.SrcIn);
     Control.ThumbDrawable.SetColorFilter(defaultColorFilter);
} 
else 
{
     #pragma warning disable CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
     Control.ThumbDrawable.SetColorFilter(_defaultColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn);
     #pragma warning restore CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
}
```